# Uncaught TypeError: r.current.contains is not a function in kendo DriopDownList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

While working with Kendo React, I wanted to add a Kendo DropDownList. I tried to fill the list with data like this:

```
Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: -1, name: null }
​
1: Object { id: 1, name: "A" }
​
2: Object { id: 2, name: "B" }
​
3: Object { id: 3, name: "C" }
​
4: Object { id: 4, name: "D" }
​
5: Object { id: 5, name: "E" }
​
6: Object { id: 6, name: "F" }
​
7: Object { id: 77, name: "G" }
```

The data is fetched with axios and put inside useState in UseEffect:

```
const[sektor, setSektor] = useState([]);
...
...
useEffect(() => {   
      (async() =>{
        try{
          const resSektor = await services.getSektor();
          console.log(resSektor.data.rlista); //JSON above is this console log
          setSektor(resSektor.data.rlista);
        }
        catch(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      })();
     
       }, []);
```

So, 'sektor' is used as an array of objects that will fill the Kendo dropdown:

```
<DropDownList data={sektor} value={sektorV} style={{marginTop:'2%'}} onChange={handleChangeSektor} textField="name" dataItemKey="id"/>
...
...
const handleChangeSektor = (event) => {
      setSektorV(event.target.value);
    };
```

'sektorV' is a state that saves the object that is picked from the KendoDropDown and is defined like this:

```
const[sektorV, setSektorV] = useState({id: -1, name: "All"});
```

Everything seems to be correct, but when I click on the DropDown the screen goes white and this is console logged:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.current.contains is not a function
...
Uncaught TypeError: _utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.getItemValue(...) is null
```

I had a bunch of dropdowns in my current project and they all worked fine. Can anybody see the problem?

Comment: Just a hunch based on this limited code context, but does this error get thrown if you remove the first element with a `null` `name` property from the `resSektor.data.rlista` array? Try `setSektor(resSektor.data.rlista.slice(1));`. Or instead of `null` update *that* element's `name` property to `"ALL"` to match the initial `sectorV` state.

Comment: @DrewReese it is working now, but when I click it it still logs : "Uncaught TypeError: r.current.contains is not a function"

Comment: Does it throw that error if you comment out the `useEffect` and use *just* the empty array?

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the useEffect it still throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: r.current.contains is not a function
    listener hooks.tsx:51
    listener hooks.tsx:50
    useOnClickOutside hooks.tsx:60
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 20"

Comment: Ok, seems like the empty array on the initial render is an issue. If `sektor.length` is non-zero then conditionally render the `DropDownList` component. If there's still an issue with even this can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and we can inspect and debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch based on this limited code context, but I think this error is thrown because the first element has a `null` `name` property in the `resSektor.data.rlista` array.

Try `setSektor(resSektor.data.rlista.slice(1));` to remove the `null` value or instead of `null` update *that* element's `name` property to `"ALL"` to match the initial `sectorV` state.

```
useEffect(() => {   
  (async() =>{
    try {
      const resSektor = await services.getSektor();
      resSektor.data.rlista[0].name = "All";
      setSektor(resSektor.data.rlista);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```